# Matching Regular Expressions In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am trying to extract id of Android app from its url but getting extra characters.
Using replace function in sql server, below are two sample urls:

1. > https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipkart.android&hl=en  com.flipkart.android
2. > https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en_US&id=com.surveysampling.mobile.quickthoughts&referrer=mat_click_id%3Df1901cef59f79b1542d05a1fdfa67202-20150429-5128 en_US&id=com.surveysampling.mobile.quickthoughts&r

I am doing this right now:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(PREVIEW, '&hl=en',''), CHARINDEX('?', PREVIEW) + 4 , 50) 
FROM OFFERS_TABLE;
```

But for 1st I am getting `com.flipkart.android` which is correct, but for 2nd I am getting `en_US&id=com.surveysampling.mobile.quickthoughts&r`.

I want to remove `en_US&id` from starting of it and `&r` from its end.

Can someone help me with any post or url from where I can refer?

Comment: Is `com.` always present in your app id ? Because if that is the case then [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/jD6eI5/1) will work for your situation.

Comment: No, for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.elitepartner.android, in this com is not present.

Comment: Okay what are the all possible beginnings of strings, like `com`, `de`. Could you give the list ? Integrating that list in the above given solution will work.

Comment: Actually it can be anything from google play. It will have '&id=', we need to read after '=' upto the last alphabet. Like if it is 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en_US&id=com.surveysampling.mobile.quickthoughts&referrer=mat_click_id%3Df1901cef59f79b1542d05a1fdfa67202-20150429-5128', then we need 'com.surveysampling.mobile.quickthoughts'

Comment: If there were a list of just words the `id` is beginning with, it will save my day from coming up with a complicated regex.

Comment: Please don't give much of your time. I will split the string by '&' and then take the substring after 'id=', this I will do in C# code and then insert into the database. :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just posted an answer, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do is extract the string preceded by `id=` until the `&` is found which is separator for variables in URL. Taking this condition I came up with following  regex.

**Regex**: `(?<=id=)[^&]*`

**Explanation**: It uses the `lookbehind` assertion that is the string is preceded by `id=` until the first  `&` is found.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD6eI5/3)**</kbd>

Comment: @AlokGupta: My day is saved now. :D

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've made some assumptions of lengths.  The the &r is appearing because that is 50 characters.  You are also getting the en_US because you assumed 4 characters at the beginning but your second string has more.  Perhaps you can split on & and then look for the variable that begins with id=.

it seems like a function like this would help.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Comment: Hey @Joel, yes I modified that already. Thanks for your note.